# c# error in regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression where the input is just arabic, space and numbers (but with no predefined order)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[\u0600-\06ff\\s0-9]*");
```

when the input is `4`, this is the exception:

`parsing "[؀-`

`{"parsing \"[؀-\06ff\\s0-9]*\" - [x-y] range in reverse order."}`

Comment: the second item of the range lacks 'u' in the '\u'

Comment: @PW. so u mean to change it to \\u?

Comment: In other words, `\u0600` is an underscore `\06ff` is not a valid unicode point.

Comment: no I mean turn \u0600-\06ff into \u0600-\u06ff

Comment: @PW. I am trying that and will update you

Comment: @PW. there is no exception now but it is not working as it is expected, I entered an English letter and the result is `true` but it should be false because that regular expression is just for arabic and number and space. not english letter. why please?

Comment: @Jerry could you help me please in this please?

Comment: Please put more of your code, so that at least someone can try reproducing it completely if run as is without changing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about following code line to validate that the entire string contains only Arabic letters, whitespaces and digits using [verbatim-string-literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx)?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\u0600-\u06ff\s\d]+$");
```

Or with regluar string literal:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[\\u0600-\\u06ff\\s\\d]+$");
```

By removing `^` (begin of string) and `$` (end of string) the expression would search for 1 or more strings consisting only of arabic letters, whitespaces and digits instead of validating if the entire string consists of only arabic letters, whitespaces and digits (and is not empty).